# Alter method visibility without redefining method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, methods, visibility

In the Spree framework, the [`Product`](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-3-stable/core/app/models/spree/product.rb) model defines a private method called `build_variants_from_option_values_hash`.

This method is normally called internally by an `after_create` callback, and it is declared as `private` within the class. I would like to use of this method outside of the normal "create" lifecycle and call it directly to, however since it is declared privately, unfortunately it is not visible outside of the class.

**Question:** Is there a way to alter / modify the visibility of a method without redefining it?

Using `class_eval`, I can redefine the method in a product decorator outside of the `private` area, and this does do the trick. However, I feel like completely copying over an entire method simply to change its visibility is an unnecessary "monkey patching"-type approach. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: why don't just sent args to it with `send :private_method, *args`?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Oh I see. I didn't consider that for some reason. Thank you, that does appear to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though @МалъСкрылевъ's approach is more sensible, IMO, you could alternatively create a public alias of the method:

```
Product.class_eval do

  alias_method :public_build_variants, :build_variants_from_option_values_hash
  public :public_build_variants

end
```

which could now be used as

```
p = Product.new
p.public_build_variants
```

Comment: Ah I see, very nice, I hadn't considered aliasing either. In regards to the `public :public_build_variants` portion, is there any reason I might want to avoid directly changing the method visibility, as opposed to its alias (in other words: `public :build_variants_from_option_values_hash`)?

Comment: There is usually very good reason why the gem developer marked the method as private. I know nothing about the gem in question, so I can't speak to the exact motivations in this case. Generally private methods are not intended for use by developers, allowing the gem maintainer to modify/rename/remove such functionality without BC breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Approach with redefining visibility of a method in `ruby` is not good. But however you are able to do this by getting and redefining the same method to public space as follows:

```
class CC
   private
   def private_method
   end
end
CC.new.private_method # => NoMethodError: private method `private_method' called for #<CC:0x8166144>

method = CC.instance_method(:private_method)
CC.send(:remove_method, :private_method)
CC.send(:define_method, :private_method, method)
CC.new.private_method # => nil
```

but the proper way to invoke the private method is to use `#send` public method as follows:

```
object.send :private_method, *args
```

Comment: Yeah, both answers were very good, and I had a hard time deciding which one to accept. However I decided to go with the other one because of the point Deefour brought up in his comment; that, since the name of the method could change (since it is declared as private, the developers may feel free to rename as they need), if I use Deefour's method, I would only need to change the name once to update my code, because I've declared it in the model like he described. Now, I could do something similar with your method, but I felt the alias version was a bit cleaner.

Comment: @PaulRichter the good method is to use `#send`, bit alias or get/assign =)

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite understand what you were saying with *bit alias or get/assign*. However, if you feel the `send` method is a better approach, I'm completely 100% open, if you'd like to help me understand your position. As I said, both methods seemed, more or less, equally as good to me, other than the "cleanliness" thing I mentioned. Why do you think `#send` might be a better approach?

Comment: @PaulRichter the better because it is not intoduced into class structure. it is just an indirect call to private method, like direct to public.